# VBA copying values from one sheet to another with specified cells to insert in

Tags: excel, vba

i want to copy all values from one sheet to another, and it copies normal, but for one cell it copies string TRUE , how can i fix that and why is that happening?

This is my code:

```
Sub Unos_povrata()

Dim rw As Long
Dim cl As Integer
Dim Dest As Range


cl = 1 ' A stupac

rw = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("zbirna").Cells(65535, cl).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Set Dest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("zbirna").Cells(rw, cl + 66) 'F1
Dest.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("porudzbenica").Range("F1") '
Set Dest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("zbirna").Cells(rw, cl) 'A4
Dest.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("porudzbenica").Range("A23") '
Set Dest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("zbirna").Cells(rw, cl + 1) 'B4
Dest.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("porudzbenica").Range("B23") '

Set Dest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("zbirna").Cells(rw, cl + 65) 'AH4
Dest.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("porudzbenica").Range("AH23") '
Dest.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("porudzbenica").Range("C23:AH23").Select

    Selection.ClearContents

End Sub
```

Also, i must mention, if i delete lines

```
Dest.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("porudzbenica").Range("C23:AH23").Select

        Selection.ClearContents
```

Than it copies normal values, but problem is when i want to insert new row of values it deletes previous row.

Comment: If you really are just trying to clear the cell contents with the last two lines, then get rid of `Dest.Value = ` and replace `Select` with `ClearContents`.  You don't need `Select` or `Selection`.

Comment: @DarrellH I solved problem with that, first i do Select.Range(C23:Ah23) and than Selection.ClearContents

Comment: `Select.Range(C23:Ah23)` won't work - it would need to be `Range("C23:Ah23").Select`.  But please (if you value your sanity) get rid of `Select` and `Selection`, e.g. `Range("C23:AH23").Select` followed by `Selection.ClearContents` is equivalent to `Range("C23:A23").ClearContents`.